# show subcategories on hover if they exist

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

something like <div class="submenu" v-if="SUB_CATS> or v-if="SUB_CATS !== 0" doesnt work, please
help me understand

now on hover i have empty div, if there no subcats
[image]

```
<ul class="menu-categories">
      <li class="menu-item" v-for="category in MAIN_CATS"
          :key="category.id">
        <nuxt-link :to="`/category/${category.id}`" class="menu-button">
          {{ category.title }}
        </nuxt-link>
        <div class="submenu">
          <ul class="menu-sub-list">
            <li class="menu-item"
                v-for="sub in SUB_CATS(category.id)"
                :key="sub.id">
              <nuxt-link :to="`/category/${sub.id}`" class="menu-button">{{ sub.title }}</nuxt-link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You should check for the length of the SUB_CATS array if that is an array.

Comment: its not array,  SUB_CATS filterd on vuex: SUB_CATS: state => id => {
    return state.categories.filter(c => c.parent_id === id);
  }, if i try  v-if="SUB_CATS.length >= 1" - not work

Comment: I don't understand, how can it not be an array? Drops a `{{ SUB_CATS(category.id) }}` somewhere and have a look at what is being returned from the store.

Comment: its object [ { "id": 11, "title": "computers", "parent_id": 677, "count": 11 }, { "id": 59, "title": "phones", "parent_id": 677, "count": 1 },{ "id": 638, "title": "tablets", "parent_id": 677, "count": 2 }]  need some check, if object empty, sub_cat = display none, now on hover i have displayed empty div

Comment: It's an object in the sense that in javascript arrays are objects, but it clearly is an array, of objects. Therefore as @Eduard says, check the length of SUB_CATS. You will need some sort of trigger to populate your SUB_CATS array, passing the id to vuex.

Comment: ty all, it works  v-if="SUB_CATS(category.id).length !== 0"